# Find next term of the series ${-3, 2, -4/3, 8/9, -16/27}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The problem is to find out the next term of the series {$-3$, $2$, $-4/3$, $8/9$, $-16/27$}.

I have tried various things but haven't been able to come up with an answer. Is there a method to solve questions like these? Or is it just intuition? Please help.

The question actually required me to find the general term.

Comment: The terms alternate in sign. That suggests it might be a geometric progression. What is the ratio of the first 2 terms? The second 2 terms?

Comment: I think I got it now. The ratio is -2/3. I just need to add another term to take care of the alternate negative sign. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The next term problem is generally not a math problem, there is an infinity of possibilities, unless you spot a pattern. Possibly, starting from $k=0$, you have:
$$s_k = -(-2)^k.3^{1-k}\,,$$
or 
$$s_k = -3 \left(\frac{-2}{3}\right)^k\,.$$
Works for the five first terms.

In your case, it is easy to spot powers of $2$ and powers of $3$, and the alternating sign. Powers suggest computing ratios of terms. The alternating sign suggests it is not too complicated, because $-1,1,-1,-1,\ldots$ is not.

Simple techniques are computing differences or ratios, or differences of differences, etc. And recognizing standard series.  But this falls short fast with $5$ terms.

But you never know what the person who asks you the question has in mind. What would one do with $8,12,15,20,23,28,32,35,38,43,45,50,56$?

This is the cumulated number of letters from words of the lyrics of Shine on you crazy diamond, by the Pink Floyd, which I am currently listening to. So the next is $59$, because "now" follows "Remember  when you were young, you shone like the sun. Shine on you crazy diamond".

Comment: There is a pattern though. The question actually required for me to find out the general term.

Comment: @Anirudh Gangwal I answered with a potential general term. There is an infinity of possible patterns on few figures. Only some are simple enough to become interesting guesses

Comment: I got your point. But shouldn't it be k-1? Because the first term is -3 and putting k = 1 does not give you -3. So?

Comment: @Anirudh Gangwal I often start series at $0$, But you are correct, it would be simpler to start at $k=1$.